# how to handle failed silent auth error in auth0

Tags: auth0

I followed spa react quick start guide and it worked fine for more than a month. Recently i had this error and it is logged on auth0 as 'failed silent error' with no further information. I have been told that it is because of the browsers cookie updates and recommended to use new beta release of auth0-spa-js and change cache location to local storage. And it didn't work either.

The code is as follows:

auth_config.json:

```
{
    "domain": "dev.........eu.auth0.com",
    "clientId": "....eEKkQ.............",
    "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:8080",
    "audience": "https://.......herokuapp.com/v1/....",
    "cacheLocation": "localstorage"
}
```

and

react-auth0-wrapper.js:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import createAuth0Client from "@auth0/auth0-spa-js";

const DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK = () =>
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname);

export const Auth0Context = React.createContext();
export const useAuth0 = () => useContext(Auth0Context);
export const Auth0Provider = ({
    children,
    onRedirectCallback = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK,
    ...initOptions
}) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState();
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const [auth0Client, setAuth0] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [popupOpen, setPopupOpen] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
    const initAuth0 = async () => {
        const auth0FromHook = await createAuth0Client(initOptions);
        setAuth0(auth0FromHook);

        if (window.location.search.includes("code=")) {
        const { appState } = await auth0FromHook.handleRedirectCallback();
        onRedirectCallback(appState);
        }

        const isAuthenticated = await auth0FromHook.isAuthenticated();

        setIsAuthenticated(isAuthenticated);

        if (isAuthenticated) {
        const user = await auth0FromHook.getUser();
        setUser(user);
        }

        setLoading(false);
    };
    initAuth0();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []);

    const loginWithPopup = async (params = {}) => {
    setPopupOpen(true);
    try {
        await auth0Client.loginWithPopup(params);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        setPopupOpen(false);
    }
    const user = await auth0Client.getUser();
    setUser(user);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    };

    const handleRedirectCallback = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    await auth0Client.handleRedirectCallback();
    const user = await auth0Client.getUser();
    setLoading(false);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    setUser(user);
    };
    return (
    <Auth0Context.Provider
        value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        user,
        loading,
        popupOpen,
        loginWithPopup,
        handleRedirectCallback,
        getIdTokenClaims: (...p) => auth0Client.getIdTokenClaims(...p),
        loginWithRedirect: (...p) => auth0Client.loginWithRedirect(...p),
        getTokenSilently: (...p) => auth0Client.getTokenSilently(...p),
        getTokenWithPopup: (...p) => auth0Client.getTokenWithPopup(...p),
        logout: (...p) => auth0Client.logout(...p)
        }}
    >
        {children}
    </Auth0Context.Provider>
    );
};
```

What is wrong with this code, any help appreciated. Or i can use a different method, i just followed the docs, it doesn't matter as long as it authenticates.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been hanging around for a bit, but i was running into a similar issue.

As I understand it the `createAuth0Client` helper factory runs the `getTokenSilently` function by default as part of the set up to re-authenticate users every browser refresh.  The problem i was having was that the call to getTokenSilently was erroring, meaning that auth0FromHook was never set and the auth0client never set in state.  Because auth0client was undefined, it was then impossible to call loginwithredirect, which is the behaviour i wanted to achieve.

Basically i wanted it to auth silently, but if it failed, send to the log in screen, but that's impossible because the auth0client was undefined, resulting in a `cannot call loginwithredirect of undefined` error.  It seems that (sadly) in the current stable version of the @auth0/auth0-spa-js library (1.6.5 at time of writing) there is no way to bypass getTokenSilently when initialising the client.  However in the current beta (1.7.0-beta.5) [(Here is a list of versions)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/auth0-spa-js) they have exposed the Auth0Client class itself, so if you want to move to that version the code could be tweaked with something like....

```
initAuth0().catch( e => {
  const newClient = new Auth0Client(initOptions);
  setAuth(newClient);
})
```

and then in any protected components you can check the loading is finished and if isAuthenticated is still falsey, you should be able to redirect to login despite an error occurring during the getSilentToken.

== NON BETA OPTION

The alternative in the current api would be to perhaps set max_age to 0 or 1 in the initOptions, to force a re-login, and maybe setting prompt to "login" on the second attempt to initialize the authClient

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, `getTokenSilently` was failing with 400; I misconfigured Allowed Web Origins, my app is located in a directory `https://login.mydomain.com/myapp`, but the origin must be only `https://login.mydomain.com`