# Auth0 returns a 401 on token request. Auth0 logs show login is successful

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, auth0

I'm integrating auth0 from the tutorial into my own application and have encountered a couple of problems with authentication reflected in the auth0 logs.

This occurs on hitting my react login button:

#### Login.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import '../components/App.css'


const LoginButton = () => {
  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  return <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>Log In</button>;
};

export default LoginButton;
```

*However* on the Auth0 Application logs I see that I am successfully authenticated and I also get a `Failed Exchange`, `Successful Login` and a `Warning During Login`.

[image]

### Fixed Log: `Warning During Login`

Here's the text of the log for `Warning During Login`:

> You are using Auth0 development keys which are only intended for use
> in development and testing. This connection (google-oauth2) should be
> configured with your own Development Keys to enable the consent page
> to show your logo instead of Auth0's and to enable SSO for this
> connection. AUTH0 DEVELOPMENT KEYS ARE NOT RECOMMENDED FOR PRODUCTION
> ENVIRONMENTS. To learn more about Development Keys please refer to
> https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/devkeys.

This was fixed by following [these instructions](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/google) on the Auth0 website. Essentially:

1. Creating a google project and OAuth credentials
2. Adding the credentials inside my Auth0 connected apps

### Broken: `Login Successful`

The log shows that it was a successful login. However on my application, I click the Login button and the expected auth0 modal does not appear.

```
{
  "date": "2020-10-14T09:14:06.549Z",
  "type": "s",
  "connection_id": "",
  "client_id": "<MyClientId>",
  "client_name": "<MyClientName>",
  "ip": "<MyIP>",
  "user_agent": "Safari 13.1.2 / Mac OS X 10.15.6",
  "details": {
    "prompts": [],
    "completedAt": 1602666846548,
    "elapsedTime": null,
    "session_id": "m0AeJer-FhZ0rb9UFPWgvDkvN7MW36h_"
  },
  "hostname": "<MyHost>",
  "user_id": "<MyUserID>",
  "user_name": "<MyUserName>",
  "auth0_client": {
    "name": "auth0-react",
    "version": "1.1.0"
  },
  "log_id": "90020201014091409270008789595401783120816526823843168290",
  "_id": "90020201014091409270008789595401783120816526823843168290",
  "isMobile": false,
  "description": "Successful login"
}
```

And looking at the response headers in safari, the token request has `401`'d

```
URL: https://<testdomain>.auth0.com/oauth/token
Status: 401
Source: Network
Address: <testaddress>
Initiator: 
auth0-spa-js.production.esm.js:15
```

### Fixed Log: `Failed Exchange`

After ensuring that I was connecting to goole properly I saw that the issue persisted. Looking at the log I get the following under the heading of a `Failed Exchange`.

```
{
  "date": "2020-10-14T09:14:07.304Z",
  "type": "feacft",
  "description": "Unauthorized",
  "connection_id": "",
  "client_id": "<MyClientId>",
  "client_name": null,
  "ip": "<TheIP>",
  "user_agent": "Safari 13.1.2 / Mac OS X 10.15.6",
  "details": {
    "code": "*************Rw7"
  },
  "hostname": "<MyHostName>",
  "user_id": "",
  "user_name": "",
  "log_id": "90020201014091410270002070951766882711015226887425228818",
  "_id": "90020201014091410270002070951766882711015226887425228818",
  "isMobile": false
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64029906/1249379) fixed the `Failed Exchange` issue for me. Change your Auth0 Application properties settings to:

Application Type: Regular Web Application
Token Endpoint Authentication Method: None

[image]

This however, unearthed a new issue...

### Broken Log: `Failed Silent Auth`

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a number of fixes I did here so I'll document them in the answer.

### Warning During Login

This was fixed by ensuring the my credentials provider had been properly set up. In this case google. For instructions on how to add google as a credentials provider [see here](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/google).

### Failed Exchange

This was fixed by going to the auth0 dashboard application settings and modifying the setting `Application Type` to `Regular Web Application` and the setting `Token Endpoint Authentication Method` to `None`.

### Login Successful (but not really)

This disappeared once I fixed the `Failed Exchange` above.

[image]

### Failed Silent Auth

This was never "fixed" and the error still appears on the log. However the comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043648/how-to-handle-failed-silent-auth-error-in-auth0) prompted me to revisit my `Allowed Web Origins` and `Allowed Origins (CORS)` on my auth0 to the below:

`https://<mydomain>.eu.auth0.com, http://localhost:3000`

This was the last issue in the chain and I could now use login and logout as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Just changing the Authentication method to none will help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).